# Formulate everyday languages into PROLOG

Tags: prolog, logic

I need your help for a simple PROLOG program. I am very new to PROLOG so it might be a very trivial question, but I absolutely have no idea how to solve it.

There are 5 sentences I need to formulate into PROLOG code:

> -Bill owns a dog.
>
> -Every dogowner likes animals.
>
> -Every person who likes animals cannot hit an animal.
>
> -Bill or Bull hit a cat whose name is Tom.
>
> -Every cat is an animal.

I think I have the first 3 sentences:

```
dogowner(bill).
lovesanimal(X):- dogowner(X). 
not(hitting(X,animal(Y))):-lovesanimal(X).
```

The last one also is not a problem. But how do I formulate the 4th?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How you formulate things depends on the context. Furthermore Prolog only supports horn clauses. Although you can model everything in it, it sometimes requires some creativity.

Comment: Yeah I should maybe at that I want to answer the question **Who hit Tom?**.

Comment: This is not difficult i give you solutions for two and try to do your homework for the next three self: `owns(bill,dog).

likes(X,animals):-
      owns(X,dog).`

Comment: @LuaiGhunim thanks for your help.  I think then the third one should look like this:

`not(hit(X)):-likes(X,animals). ` or `hit(X):-not(likes(X,animals)).`

Comment: `hit(X) `, what does `X` hit? `cannothit(X,animal):-
     likes(X,animals).` or `hit(X,animal):- \+ likes(X,animal).` . This is `\+` used for inverting values.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim I think now I have it. If I am right, we need a list. `hit([bill,bull],cat(tom)).`
The last sentence then would be `animal(X):-cat(X).` 
And to answer the question "Who hit Tom?" we would ask `?-hit(X,cat(tom)).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Every cat is an animal":

> animal(X) :- cat(X).

"Every person who likes animals cannot hit an animal": I think the use of not(hitting(X,animal(Y))) may be confused ... I prefere use:

> can(hitting(X, Y)) :- person(X), not(lovesanimal(X)), animal(Y).

In other hand, you must say the program several 'facts' (that aren't explicited in your premises)

Tom is a cat:

> cat(tom).

Bill and Bull are persons:

> person(Bill).
>   person(Bull).

Finally, the predicate ';' use in pre-fixed notation:

> or(hits(bill, tom), hits(bull, tom)).

However, such programe don't tell you who (Bill or Bull), actually hits Tom. You need a clause like this:

> actually_hits(X, Y) :- can(hitting(X, Y)), (or(hits(X,Y),*); or(*, hits(X,Y)).

Finally, you can wish that the programe be more general; so, you can reemplace 'lovesanimal(X)' by 'likes(X, Y)':

> likes(X, Y) :- dogowner(X), animal(Y).

And, of course, the rules must be reformulated as:

> can(hitting(X, Y)) :- person(X), not(likes(X, Y)).

which say that "Every person who like something can not hit this thing''